# Apply Tooltip to diffrent datasets or pass an array to tooltip in Chart.js?

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to show multi line graph for showing profit/loss . I am able to plot graph.

```
 var niftyProfit = [];
 var niftyProfitChartData = [];
 var sum = 0;
 data.forEach(function(obj) {
 niftyProfit.push(obj.profit);
 });
for (var i in niftyProfit) {
 sum = sum + niftyProfit[i];
 niftyProfitChartData.push(sum);
}
```

obj.profit is the p/l column data. I want to populate the value, which I did in for loop for eg. consider profit = [4,2,-3,-5], then my final array to populate in chart would become  [4,6,3,-2]. I ploted data on chart which is array niftyProfitChartData , now In tooltip on hover its showing data from niftyProfitChartData .But I want to show data from niftyProfit array in tooltip . Here is Fiddle Link of what i tried till now . 
http://jsfiddle.net/zkrh7/159/